# My code has been detected virus (Sonar) by Norton

Tags: c#, .net, security, virus

That is my problem, this is the first time I have got it, I dont know why they do so. It has a sign-up form, to check user, I'm trying to send his HDD serial to my server. After success login, it will create a file to save username and password in system32. Please help me. thanks so much.

Comment: Why the hell do you save data in system32? A normal unprivileged application doesn't even have write access to that directory (though windows may transparently redirect it to prevent crappy or old applications from breaking)

Comment: @CodesInChaos could you use more friendly words instead of things like "Why the hell" :P It really makes new users (rep < 100) feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @nevets: True, but the message 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks so much, but i have a same problem when trying to change to Program Data. Pls help me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't try to write to system32. No normal application should do that, and Norton does the right thing preventing it.

Save user data to %AppData% instead. Also, never save passwords as plain text. You can use DPAPI for securing stored passwords.

Comment: hanks so much, but i have a same problem when trying to change to Program Data. Pls help me :(

Comment: Don't write to "C:\Program Data" either. Use %AppData%, like I suggested. %AppData% is an environment variable that points to "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming". This is the place where applications are meant to write to.

Comment: By the way, I suspect you are running the program with admin privileges. Don't do that, unless absolutely necessary! You can't write to system32 etc. without admin privileges, and that is a good thing.

Comment: Also note that even when your program no longer does anything suspicious, Norton may have remembered it and detects the fixed version as a variant of a program that it previously detected as virus. Check the documentation whether you can make Norton "forget" self-learned virus definitions.

Comment: thank bro, that's right, norton remember from older version. it has a high risk warning :D